# JSONObject parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

Here is the way i was going to do it but I get an error in the line `JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(i);`:

> Error:(95, 57) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Maybe there is a better way of doing this process , please help

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS, "GET",
                param, token);
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject orders = data.getJSONObject("orders");

        Log.d("JSON DATA", data.toString());
        Log.d("JSON ORDERS", orders.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(i);
            imageurl = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
            Log.d("IDK", imageurl);
            title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE).substring(0, 20);
            price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
            status = c.getString(TAG_PSTATUS);
            symbol = c.getString(TAG_PRICESYMBOL);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
            map.put(TAG_PSTATUS, status);
            map.put(TAG_PRICESYMBOL, symbol);
            map.put(TAG_IMAGE, imageurl);
            orderList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think orders should be a `JSONArray`

Comment: AFAIK your json is badly formatted. But if not and you want to iterate orders, then you should treat it as a JSONArray and not an object

Comment: the guy with the api part made it like it , is there no other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `orders` object is a `JSONObject` (with the order IDs being used as keys and the complete order objects as values), but in your code you're treating it as a `JSONArray`.

You probably want to change your loop as follows:

```
Iterator<String> orderIterator = orders.keys();

while (orderIterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(orderIterator.next());
    // ...
}
```

The call to [`keys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) will return an [iterator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html) over the object's keys (in this case order IDs). Then it's just a matter of using the iterator to loop over all the keys, and retrieve each order object using [`getJSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)).

Comment: can you please provide me with documentation on this kind of operations please

Comment: I just got it from the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html I'll update my answer with the relevant links.

Comment: thank you ,sir but now i have another trouble , when the listview is loading more times(to fast) data disapears , can i add a time delay like 5 seconds 
(i know it's because of time delay it had already happend with me )

Comment: That will have to be a new question. It's no longer related to the JSON parsing, so you'll have to create a new question and include the relevant code that will allow people to solve it.